# C++ operator overloading << with vector

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, operators

Hey guys I am new to C++ and I have a problem with this operator: (Also new in stackoverflow)

This is my class TestList:

```
class TestList{
public:
    TestList() : listItems(10), position(0){};
    TestList(int k) : listItems(k), position(0){};
    int listItems;
    int position;
    std::vector<int> arr;
};


//my current operator is: What should be changed?
ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const TestList& tlist, int input){
    os << tlist.arr.push_back(input);
    return os;
}
//

int main() {
testList testlist(5);
 testlist << 1 << 2 << 3; //how should I overload the operator to add these number to testlist.arr ?
 return 0;
}
```

I hope someone could help me or can give me any tips? :)

Comment: Does it *look* like your operator is receiving a `std::ostream&` ? Then the return type and current body would not seem appropriate. Start with that. and since `operator <<` is a *binary* operator, a list of three operands isn't correct either. You'll probably find [Operator Overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the following

```
TestList & operator <<( TestList &tlist , int input )
{
    tlist.arr.push_back( input );
    return tlist;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestList{
public:
    TestList() : listItems(10), position(0){};
    TestList(int k) : listItems(k), position(0){};
    int listItems;
    int position;
    std::vector<int> arr;
};

TestList & operator <<( TestList &tlist , int input )
{
    tlist.arr.push_back( input );
    return tlist;
}

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const TestList &tlist )
{
    for ( const auto &item : tlist.arr )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    TestList testlist(5);

    testlist << 1 << 2 << 3;

    std::cout << testlist << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3
```

You can even write instead of these two statements

```
testlist << 1 << 2 << 3;

std::cout << testlist << '\n';
```

only one statement

```
std::cout << ( testlist << 1 << 2 << 3 ) << '\n';
```

Pay attention to that there is a typo in your declaration

```
testList testlist(5);
```

There should be

```
TestList testlist(5);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me out. :) I understand it now ! :D

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are absolutely correct, I just want to say something general on `operator<<`. It always has the signature `T operator<<(U, V)`, since it is always a binary operator, so it has to have exactly two arguments. Since the chain

```cpp
a << b << c;
```

is evaluated as

```cpp
(a << b) << c;
// That calls
operator<<(operator<<(a, b), c);
```

the types `T` and `U` should normally be the same, or at least compatible.

Furthermore, it is possible but very weird to assign the result of `operator<<` to something (like `result = (a << b)`)). A good rule of thumb is "My code should not be weird". Therefore the type `T` should mostly be a reference (so `X&`) since otherwise it would only be a temporary copy that is unused. And that is pretty useless most of the time.

So in 90% of all cases, your `operator<<` should have the signature
`T& operator<<(T&, V);`